# You have $NVM_DIR set to "/root/.nvm", but that directory does not exist. Check your profile files and environment

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, installation, nvm

I'm trying to reinstall nvm (as a new user) after uninstalling it (as root) but clearly it didn't work. Please tell me how to fix this.

```
user@site-beta:~/htdocs$ curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.37.2/install.sh | bash
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 13527  100 13527    0     0   105k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  105k
You have $NVM_DIR set to "/root/.nvm", but that directory does not exist. Check your profile files and environment.
```

Edit: my advice is to give up on NVM and just install node normally, because clearly NVM isnt making it any easier.

Comment: The `NVM_DIR` variable is set in your shell profile somewhere (.bashrc or .bash_profile). Remove the line that sources `. /root/.nvm/nvm.sh` and try the install again in a new shell.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was editing /root/.profile and changing the path of the NVM_DIR as root, change that line to this:

```
export NVM_DIR="/home/<USERNAME>/.nvm"
```

replace USERNAME with the account you would like to run the script with, then run

```
source /root/.profile
```

After that switch to the desired user account using su command:

```
su <USERNAME>
```

And finally run the nvm install script one more time:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | bash
```

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when there was nvm already present under a different user profile on the same computer. Here's a simple set of steps that can help you resolve. Assuming you have access/rights on your computer to modify paths/directories and default variables.

1. (make sure to replace 'USERNAME' above with your user profile/userid on the computer)

```bash
export NVM_DIR="/home/USERNAME/.nvm"
```

2. Install nvm again:

```bash
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | bash
```

3. Refresh the shell file:

```bash
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

4. Ensure nvm has been installed. If it isn't, try to kill the terminal once and open a new terminal and try `nvm -v` again:

```bash
nvm -v
```

Answer (score -2):

### Steps to install node using nvm

1. Before piping the command through to `bash`, it is always a good idea to audit the script to make sure it isn’t doing anything you don’t agree with. You can do that by removing the `| bash` segment at the end of the `curl` command:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh
```

2. Take a look and make sure you are comfortable with the changes it is making. When you are satisfied, run the command again with `| bash` appended at the end. The URL you use will change depending on the latest version of nvm, but as of right now, the script can be downloaded and executed by typing:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash
```

3. This will install the nvm script to your user account. To use it, you must first source your `.bashrc` file:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

4. Now, you can ask NVM which versions of Node are available:

```
nvm list-remote
```

5. It’s a very long list! You can install a version of Node by typing any of the released versions you see. For instance, to get version v14.16.0, you can type:

```
nvm install v14.16.0
```

6. You can verify that the install was successful using the same technique from the other sections, by typing:

```
node -v
```

[Checkout NVM Official Docs](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)